# Solving biharmonic equation for $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am using [Evans - Partial Differential Equations](https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/Partial_Differential_Equations/Xnu0o_EJrCQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&printsec=frontcover) to draw inspiration for solving the biharmonic homogeneous equations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n = 2$.

$$
\Delta^2 u = 0
$$

My attempt is to write the following equivalent system and solve one equation at the time

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\Delta u = v \\
\Delta v = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The solution for $\Delta v = 0$ I refer to Evans which yields

$$
\Delta v = 0 \iff v = A\log r + B
$$

where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. My contribution here is then to solve

$$
\Delta u= A\log r + B
$$

With the change of variables above I can write

$$
\Delta = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 = \left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{d}{dr}\right) \frac{d}{dr}
$$

Therefore I can equivalently solve

$$
\left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{d}{dr}\right) \frac{d}{dr}u= A\log r + B.
$$

Again taking inspiration from Evans I get the following system

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{d}{dr}\right) w = A\log r + B \\
\frac{d}{dr} u = w
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I solve the first equation of this last system using integrating factor

$$
\left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{d}{dr}\right) w = A\log r + B \iff \left(1 + r \frac{d}{dr}\right) w = r \left(A\log r + B\right) \iff \frac{d}{dr} \left( rw \right) = r \left(A\log r + B\right) \iff
rw = \frac{r^2}{2} \left(A\log r + B\right) - \frac{A}{4}r^2 + C \iff w = \frac{r}{2} \left(A\log r + B\right) - \frac{A}{4}r + \frac{C}{r}.
$$

Now I can solve the second equation

$$
w = \frac{d}{dr} u = \frac{r}{2} \left(A\log r + B\right) - \frac{A}{4}r + \frac{C}{r}
$$

where I integrate side by side and this gives me

$$
u = \frac{r^2}{4} \left(A\log r + B\right) - \frac{A}{8} r^2 - \frac{A}{8}r^2 + C \log r + D = \frac{r^2}{4} \left(A\log r + B\right) - \frac{A}{4} r^2 + C \log r + D.
$$

Rearranging a bit I get

$$
u = \left(C + \frac{A}{4}r^2 \right) \log r + \left(B - A\right)\frac{r^2}{4} + D.
$$

**Question**: Is this solution correct? also the procedure being used is it the standard one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reference to an old book with the similar solution to the biharmonic equation. I've found it through some later articles referring back to it, so it is perhaps one of a standard references:

Greenberg. Applications of Green's Functions in Science and Engineering
1971, 2015

p. 125 onwards

you can download a djvu scan here:
https://ebin.pub/applications-of-greens-functions-in-science-and-engineering-0486797961.html